# java Object copying,Array index out of bound

Tags: java, vector, copy

I have a class "schedule".

```
public class schedule {
    public int P;
    public int K;
    Vector<Vector<element>> r;

    public schedule(int p, int k) {
    this.P = p;
    this.K = k;
    r = new Vector<Vector<element>>(5 * P);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 * p; i++) {
        Vector<element> v = new Vector<element>();
        r.add(v);
    }
}

schedule(schedule s){
    P = s.P;
    K = s.K;
    r = s.r;
}

public ArrayList<schedule> getSuccessors() {
    ArrayList<schedule> routine;
    routine = new ArrayList<schedule>();
    schedule temp= new schedule(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < r.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < r.get(i).size(); j++) {
            for (int k = 1; k < r.size(); k++) {
                //System.out.println(r.elementAt(i).size());
                //System.out.println(r.elementAt(j).size());
                //System.out.println("credit "+ r.elementAt(i).elementAt(j).credit);
                if (!r.elementAt(k).contains(r.elementAt(i).elementAt(j))) {
                    temp.r = r;
                    temp.r.elementAt(k).add(r.elementAt(i).elementAt(j));
                    temp.r.get(i).remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
        routine.add(temp);
    }
    return routine;
}
}
```

Whenever  the code is executed i get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0 error message at getSuccessors() method.Any help is greatly welcome.

Comment: Not related to the question, but is there a particular reason to use Vector? If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList instead (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing elements of the arrays while doing the loop. That is always a bad idea, since your contract of the index being valid might not hold anymore after you removed the element.

If you want to remove elements while iterating, you should use `Iterator` and its `remove()` method. And if you're inside a nested collection and you're removing an elements from the external collection while you're in the internal collection, delay it until after you've finished the external loop (either by using `break` or by setting a `toRemove` flag and then deleting the element after you're done with the internal loop).